# How to put FK constraint on two tables in mysql with one table with InnoDB and other is MyISAM

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1005

Reason: liquibase.exception.JDBCException:

```
Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `User` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_location` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `Location`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE:
          Caused By: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `UserLocation` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_location_location_id` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `Location`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE:
          Caused By: Can't create table 'usiapp_db.#sql-399a_177a7' (errno: 150)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You have to convert your MyISAM table to InnoDB if you want create foreign keys to or from it:

```
ALTER TABLE MyIsamTable ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You can do this dynamically, without taking down your database.

Comment: That is useful. But what if I want to add SPATIAL index on my table column. As SPACIAL indexes are not supported by InnoDB. So if I make alter table to use InnoDB, I have to loose SPATIAL index. So can we have SPATIAL indexes and FK both!

Comment: Currently you cannot have both (foreign keys and spatial indexes), which is too bad. So you have to choose. For some possible workaround see [How Do I Get Spatial Index Feature If I Mainly use InnoDB](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19306/how-do-i-get-spatial-index-feature-if-i-mainly-use-innodb).